# Is it possible to reference native Android platform string?

Tags: android

When I write in my strings.xml "android:strings/" I only get a few strings, is there the possibility to access any string of the Android platform and how?
Bonus questions: is there a site where I can explore all strings, I remember finding such a page in the past but was not able to find something like that anymore, grepcode does not have Android 6 yet to explore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most strings on the Android platform are declared private - meaning developers should not be trying to use them. They may not exist, or the IDs may change between different builds of Android.

However, if you know *for certain* that a particular string will exist on a device, you can reference a private string using the `@*` prefix:

```
<TextView android:text="@*android:string/data_usage_warning_body" />
```

Just **don't do this** if you expect the App to work across multiple devices and Android versions.

Bonus: [androidxref](http://androidxref.com) is a good site for exploring the Android source. You can find some resource strings [here](http://androidxref.com/6.0.1_r10/xref/frameworks/base/core/res/res/values/strings.xml)

Answer (score 0):

You can check out the github repository for Android. It contains all the resources including the string.xml. The following link should bring you to the marshmallow resource folder: [Android on Github](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/tree/marshmallow-cts-release/core/res/res)

I don't know if you can just reference those string directly.